# Does it anyway matter where you place your global variable in java?

Tags: java, variables

It may be a basic question, but I would like to clear some confusion that I have. Does it in any way matter where you place your global variable? for example;

```
int globalVariable = 3;

//Some Method here which DOES NOT use the globalVariable
```

different from:

```
//Some methods here which don't use the globalVariable

int globalVariable = 3

//Some methods here which use the globalVariable
```

Comment: `globalVariable` is not a global variable. You need to supply more context in order to decide if the placement matters or not.

Comment: Of course it matters. It doesn't make a difference in your examples though.

Comment: The answer is *probably* no difference. The situation in which it would matter is if any of the methods (or other initializers) directly or indirectly refer to the value before it is initialized to 1.

Comment: It would only throw errors if you attempted to use a variable before initializing it.

Comment: @GlenDespaux What error? Al variables are initialized with default values.

Comment: @talex Sorry, I did mean declare, not initialize

Comment: @GlenDespaux only if it is declared as `final` and this rule not strict. There are several ways to overcome it.

Comment: Strictly speaking, there are no global variables in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relative placement of field declarations inside a class is relevant in two situations:

- **The field is referenced inside initialization expressions of other fields** - in this situation the field being referenced must be declared before the field that references it; otherwise, the code would not compile with "illegal forward reference" error. The above is also true for fields referenced from anonymous initialization blocks placed in front of field's declaration ([demo](http://ideone.com/Li0Btq)).
- **Field initializer has side effects** - in this situation placing the initializer before or after other initializers changes the order of side effects.

Here is an illustration of the second point:

```
class Test {
    int a = foo("hello");
    int b = foo("world");
    static int foo(String s) {
        System.out.println(s);
        return 3;
    }
}
```

The above prints

```
hello
world
```

each time a `Test` object is constructed. If you move the declaration of `a` to after the declaration of `b`, the printout would change to

```
world
hello
```

Comment: You forgot about anonymous constructor `{ /*some code that use variable*/ }`

Comment: @talex That's a fair point - anonymous constructor blocks fall into the same category as plain field initializers. Thanks!